# Using spring websockets on receiving messges stomp.js throws this error,uncaught type error: onrecieve is not a function(..) stomp.js

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, stomp, spring-websocket

I want to use websockets with spring and using this blog http://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring settings to make it work,but its not working .getting error:

uncaught type error: onrecieve is not a function(..) stomp.js

getting this error on using websockets, stockjs nd stomp with spring project.i m using spring 4.2.4 and tomcat 7.0.56.

any idea why i m getting this error?

my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">



<display-name>CometdWireChatRE</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
```

```
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>chatbook</display-name>
<servlet-name>chatbook</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>chatbook</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>
    classpath:/com/chatbook/web/xmlfileconfig/daoAccesspackage.xml 
    classpath:/com/chatbook/web/xmlfileconfig/serviceaccesspackage.xml 
    classpath:/com/chatbook/web/xmlfileconfig/cacheMan.xml
    classpath:/com/chatbook/web/xmlfileconfig/configpackage.xml
 </param-value>
 </context-param>


   <description>Wirechat Database</description>
 <resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/wirechatDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>



 <listener>
 <listener-   class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener> 

</web-app>
```

my class to enable websocket:

```
package com.chatbook.web.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import  org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import  org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

 @Configuration

 @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker

  public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
}
}
```

my controller:

package com.chatbook.web.controllers;

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.chatbook.web.config.Message;
import com.chatbook.web.config.OutputMessage;

 @Controller

  public class AtmosController {
//@Autowired
//SimpMessagingTemplate  template;

public AtmosController() {
    System.out.println("atm");
}



    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")

    public OutputMessage send(Message message) throws Exception {
    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
    System.out.println(message);
    return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText(), time);

    //template.convertAndSend("/topic/messages", new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText(), time));
}



}
```

Comment: can you show your configurations

Comment: hey its just same like in this blog  http://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring  i just copy and paste  that blog code. and my rest configurations like my web.xml and other i mention in the question.

Comment: have you defined WebSocketConfig and annotated with @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker?

Comment: i did check my config file i added them

Comment: it connect to socket and also send message to destination url address in browser console . but the problem is that it never call method 'send' defined in controller in  server side and i don't get anything back. so i thing it has problem using this annotation @MessageMapping